# cannot load such file -- sassc running gem rails_admin with rails 7.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-7, sassc

I am having a problem with plain new project created with ruby on rails  (ruby 3.1.2 and rails 7.0.4). After running `rails new someproject`command project initialization finishing well. I can run project also I can add controller and it looks okay. My problem begins when adding `rails_admin` gem. Tried few versions latest one at this time 3.1 and also some preview versions and also 3.0.

After adding geminto Gemfile and running `bundle` command, also running `rails g rails_admin:install` finishing fine. After that when I trying to open `http://locahost:3000/admin` I am getting error:

```
LoadError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard
cannot load such file -- sassc

if Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FALLBACK_SCAN.equal?(resolved)
      if (cursor = Bootsnap::LoadPathCache.loaded_features_index.cursor(string_path))
        ret = require_without_bootsnap(path)
        resolved = Bootsnap::LoadPathCache.loaded_features_index.identify(string_path, cursor)
        Bootsnap::LoadPathCache.loaded_features_index.register(string_path, resolved)
        return ret
```

At first suggestions I tried to add `gem "sassc-rails"` but that produce another error:

```
SassC::SyntaxError in RailsAdmin::Main#dashboard

Error: File to import not found or unreadable: rails_admin/src/rails_admin/styles/base.
        on line 2:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin.scss
>> @import "rails_admin/src/rails_admin/styles/base";

 $fa-font-path: ".";
@import "rails_admin/src/rails_admin/styles/base";
```

[image]
[image]

Also, tried to add some net-http gem, tried to do update of the referencing path to this base directory in my app. But it just produce another error. Not so clean solution for this kind of problems, for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solution, it looks like we must have already installed '**bootstrap**'.
So, if I create new **rails 7** project with `rails new someproject -j esbuild --css bootstrap` and after that add the **rails_admin gem** and install it regularly.

My rails_admin 3.1 is accessible on **/admin** path and looks okay.

Comment: I've had another error though my app was initially generated with bootstrap and esbuild.
File **app/assets/config/manifest.js** was missing in my app.
There should be `//= link_tree ../images` and `//= link_tree ../builds`