# You need to merge "scripts" error while installing rails_admin --- > rails g rails_admin:install

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

i'm trying to install rails_admin from: https://github.com/railsadminteam/rails_admin

and at the last step

it gives me this error:

```
append  config/initializers/assets.rb
           -  Add scripts to package.json
You need to merge "scripts": {
  "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin.scss:./app/assets/builds/rails_admin.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
} into the existing scripts in your package.json.
Taking 'build:css' as an example, if you're already have application.sass.css for the sass build, the resulting script would look like:
  sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css ./app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin.scss:./app/assets/builds/rails_admin.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules
```

tried updating the package.json to this:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.63.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin.scss:./app/assets/builds/rails_admin.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
}
```

and run rails g rails_admin:install
again but still the same error.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471820/cannot-load-such-file-sassc-running-gem-rails-admin-with-rails-7-0-4) fixed my problem

Answer (score -1):

```
Rails: 7.0.6 
Ruby: 3.2.2
```

In `package.json` you have to replace build:css:

```
- "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin.scss:./app/assets/builds/rails_admin.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
+ "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css ./app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin.scss:./app/assets/builds/rails_admin.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
```

After replacement you need to run `yarn build:css`.

You are all done!

Comment: @1684155 , in the question they tried to reinstall `rails g rails_admin:install` but as answer I wrote `yarn build:css`.